# Ambiguity in C11 regarding _Generic statements?

Tags: c, generics, c11, ambiguity

As much as I go over the C11 standard, I can't see a resolution to the question of whether lvalues are converted to rvalues when they appear as the controlling expression in a _Generic expression. For example, does the following function return 1 or 0?

```
int func()
{
   const int x;
   return _Generic( x, int: 1, default: 0 );
}
```

In the standard, lvalue conversion is defined as follows (6.3.2.1.2):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, the unary & operator, the ++ operator, the -- operator, or the left operand of the . operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called lvalue conversion. If the lvalue has qualified type, the value has the unqualified version of the type of the lvalue; additionally, if the lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic version of the type of the lvalue; otherwise, the value has the type of the lvalue...

It apparently follows that func returns 1. The controlling expression, 'x', undergoes lvalue conversion as it does not appear in one of the excepted circumstances. Therefore, it has type **int** and 1 is selected.

On the other hand, the standard says (6.5.1.1.2):

> ...The type name in a generic association shall specify a complete object type other than a variably modified type...

and (6.3.2.1.3):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue...

The only reason to explicitly rule out variably modified types that I can see is to allow for arrays but not for variable length arrays (since the type is already required to be a complete object type). Since it seems clear that lvalue conversion and pointer conversion either both apply or neither applies to _Generic controlling expressions, this suggests that conversion does not take place. Otherwise the exclusion of variably modified types is superfluous and extremely confusing.

This seems to me to justify the argument that lvalue conversion is implicitly only relevant to evaluated statements, and the controlling expression of a _Generic is not evaluated. By this understanding, there is no lvalue conversion, and in the example given 'x' has its unconverted type of **const int** and so func returns 0.

Is there anything in the standard that clarifies this issue? In particular, would func have the same return value on any complying implementation? Finally, are the popular compilers (e.g., clang, gcc, etc.) consistent on this issue?

I should note that I am using the committee draft of the standard, so if the final version clarifies this then please let me know.

Comment: This is an open issue in the standards defect report process. See https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2015/05/11/the-controlling-expression-of-_generic/ for more. Please give me feedback there, if you have new observations about the behavior of existing compilers.

Comment: Note that the controlling expression is not evaluated, so most of the quotes in your question do not come into play (they relate to the evaluation of expressions).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Jens Gustedt in comments, this was a known issue in C11 which later got fixed in C17. C17 6.5.1 §2 adds the following sentence:

> The type of the controlling expression is the type of the expression as if it had undergone an lvalue conversion, array to pointer conversion, or function to pointer conversion.

Where a foot note further notes that lvalue conversion means that type qualifiers are dropped.

Therefore in C17 or later, `_Generic( x, int: 1, default: 0 )` is guaranteed to always return `1` for `const int x;`. Some newer compilers give warnings in case you attempt something like `const int:` in the association list.